# How to filter results when retrieving in SQL using WITH and UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have no idea what is going on here, SQL-wise. The code is the following:

```
WITH t ( clientId, code, cname, rootId, active ) 
AS (
    SELECT clientID, code, cName, clientID AS rootId, active
    FROM clients AS [mt]
    WHERE [sub] = 0 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT mt.clientID, mt.code, mt.cName, t.[rootId], mt.active
    FROM clients AS [mt]
    INNER JOIN t ON t.clientId = mt.[sub]
), roots AS (
    SELECT rootId
    FROM t
    WHERE cname LIKE '%abb%' OR code LIKE '%abb%'
)    
SELECT [t].[code], [t].[cname], [t].[clientID]
FROM t 
INNER JOIN roots rt ON [rt].[rootId] = [t].[rootId]
WHERE [t].active='True'
```

This code works fine but I've been asked to change it. In the clients table, there is a new bit field called `isParent`. I need the results to only present if `isParent='False'`. Currently, I get the following columns back:

```
code.    cName.    clientID
```

I've tried several ways of appending `AND isParent='False'` but I keep getting an error stating something about too few columns in "t".

Comment: Show us your code where you attempt to add the new condition.

Comment: In wich table we can find this column [isParent] ?

Comment: isParent is in the clients table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is performing hierarchical recursion on the clients table.  The condition isParent='False' seems to suggest you're attempting to remove non-root rows from the base of the recursion.  So I added the condition to the top SELECT statement (above the UNION ALL) only.  Also, I removed the unnecessary brackets and reformatted the code for readability (at least imo).

```
with 
t(clientid, code, cname, rootid, active) as (
    select clientid, code, cname, clientid as rootid, active 
    from clients mt
    where sub = 0 
          and isParent='False'
    union all
    select mt.clientid, mt.code, mt.cname, t.rootid, mt.active 
    from clients mt 
         join t on t.clientid = mt.sub), 
roots(rootid) as (
    select rootid 
    from t
    where cname like '%abb%' 
          or code like '%abb%') 
select t.code, t.cname, t.clientid 
from t 
     join roots rt on rt.rootid = t.rootid 
where t.active='true';
```